# Is it possible to compile pgplot with mpif90?

Tags: plot, fortran

I am trying to compile pgplot with mpif90 in a Linux. I am able to compile pgplot with gfortran and g77. However, I need it to be compatible with another program that was compiled with mpif90. Unfortunately, it is not possible for me to reinstall the other program (not pgplot) with gfortran. Is there a way to compile pgplot with mpif90?

Edit: I used mpif90 -v to check the compiler. It is pgf90. I wasn't aware that mpif90 was a wrapper...sorry. I will try to compile it with pgf90.

Comment: Try typing `mpif90 --version`, this will show you what compiler + version is actually being used when you compile with `mpif90`. If this matches what you used to compile pgplot originally then you should be ok. If you run `mpif90 -show` then you will see the command actually used (e.g. you could imagine replacing mpif90 with that command everywhere).

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Are you asking how to change the compiler when executing `configure `. As @d_1999 says it is a good bet that `mpif90` is just gfortran on you computer although it might be something else and then just use that one for pgplot.

Comment: @VladimirF I didn't realize that mpif90 was a wrapper. I will try with the compiler "under the hood" and ask another question if I cannot solve it. Thank you ~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mpif90` (and `mpifort`) compilers are actually just wrappers which invoke "standard" compilers with a set of extra flags that ensure the correct mpi libraries etc. are automatically linked. You can usually run `mpif90 -show` in order to see what command is actually being used. For example running this on a local machine I see

```
> mpif90 -show
/usr/bin/gfortran -I/path/to/openmpi/include -fexceptions -pthread -I/path/to/openmpi/lib64 \
    -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/path/to/openmpi/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/path/to/openmpi/lib64 -lmpi_usempi -lmpi_mpifh -lmpi
```

which indicates `mpif90` is using the system `gfortran` compiler "under-the-hood".

To explicitly answer your question, as long as you can compile pgplot with the compiler that `mpif90` uses "under-the-hood" then you should generally be able to compile pgplot with `mpif90` as well. *However* as long as the compiler that `mpif90` wraps matches what you have used to build pgplot already then you probably don't need to explicitly compile pgplot again with `mpif90`.

To actually build pgplot with mpif90 will require looking into the pgplot build system and how you set the compiler. From a quick look it seems that you need to set the FCOMPL variable that appears inside the `sys_<type>/*.conf` files. (*If this is actually the main point of your question then you may wish to edit it to  make this clear*)